# asynchronous image loading jquery

Tags: html, image, css, asynchronous

Is it possible to load image asynchronously while the page is loading? The images in the code will be displayed when a user click on a button, this means that they don't display right away. Then I ask if is it possible to load the image in a sort of cache and when they need to be used they display without waiting so long?

Answer (score 1):

All image objects are loaded asynchronously by the browser.

Here is an image loader that preloads all images and then calls the start() method. When start() is called all images are fully loaded and ready to display:

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("myImage1.png");
imageURLs.push("myImage2.png");

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```